# Java heap space error in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, performance-testing

The vm hardware configuration is
Processor: Dual Core
RAM : 8GB RAM

Increased the JMETER Heap Space to 8GB but still getting as JAVA HEAP SPACE issue. Also in the Task Manager the while wrunning the script with 3 Vusers for 10minutes for debugging purpose when I looked at Task Manager Memory consumption is upto 80%.
[image]

I followed this link to find out the changes I made in Jmeter.bat file for the heap space but not getting heap sapce information.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586174/jmeter-how-to-increase-heap-size

[image]

Getting as [image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that heap setting is **really applied**. For example you need to

   - restart JMeter after changing the value in .bat file
   - you need to use the jmeter.bat file for starting JMeter
   - use 64-bit JVM as you won't be able to allocate more than 3GB with 32-bit Java
2. [Don't use GUI mode for tests execution](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
3. Add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your test plan in particular and get familiarized with [JMeter Web Testing: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter) article in general